# Trying to join Minecraft servers. my internet is up but no servers will allow access

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I cannot join any Minecraft servers. My internet is fine as all apps that require internet have been working fine. but when I go onto Minecraft, and try to connect to a server, it gives me this error message:

io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:

and I have no idea what the problem is, it's not all Minecraft, as I can play single player.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using antivirus, try disabling it for a moment and check if Minecraft is still blocked.